# Using the AspNetCompiler class

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to precompile an ASP.NET web site (not web application project) using the AspNetCompiler class, so that I don't have to run the aspnet_compiler.exe command directly.

The MSDN reference is here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124552.aspx

Has anyone gotten this to work?

The code I'm trying to run is:

```
AspNetCompiler anc = new AspNetCompiler();
anc.PhysicalPath = physicalPath;
anc.TargetPath = targetPath;
anc.VirtualPath = "/";
anc.Execute();
```

It errors with this:

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper.LogExternalProjectStarted(String message, String helpKeyword, String projectFile, String targetNames)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AspNetCompiler.Execute()

Comment: The first line of the page you linked to should be telling... _"This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."_

Answer (score 0):

If you need a tool, http://www.west-wind.com/tools/aspnetcompiler.asp from Rick Strahl is one I use if needed. I don't believe he used the class, only a GUI wrapper for the cmd line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to call it programmatically. You should use it as a build task. Take a look at

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/05/14/the-aspnet-compiler-build-task-in-visual-studio-2010-asp-net-mvc-2-projects.aspx

http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/compile-aspx-pages-at-compile-time-using-the-aspnetcompiler-build-task/